# How to validate textbox based on dropdown value in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In dropdown we have 
`Number and Decimalnumber`

if user select `Number` from dropdown text box should allow to enter only number (round number)
for example 22,33,444,345436 .

it should not allow to enter decimal values 22.2,33.33,444.3333

if user select Decimalnumber from dropdown that same text box should allow to enter 2decimals
example
22.2,33.33,444.23

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

debugger;

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.selectedvalue = "Number";


  $scope.userinput = "";

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>



<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  please select
  <select ng-model="selectedvalue">
    <option value="Number">Number</option>
    <option value="Decimalnumber">Decimalnumber</option>
  </select><br>
  <p>Selected: {{selectedvalue}}</p>

  <input type="number" ng-model="userinput">

</body>
```

how to do this please help me out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you change :

```
<input type="number" ng-model="userinput">
```

to

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="userinput">
```

then

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);


app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.selectedvalue = "Number";


  $scope.userinput = "";

  $scope.changeFun = function(e) {
    var tempInput = document.querySelector("#inputId").value;
    var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);

    if($scope.selectedvalue === "Number") {
      if ((regex.test(str) || e.which === 8)) {
          return true;
      }
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    } else if($scope.selectedvalue === "Decimalnumber") {
      var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]+$");
      var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
      if ((regex.test(str) || e.which === 8) && tempInput.indexOf(".") === -1) {
        console.log("comming 1111");
          return true;
      }


      if(tempInput.indexOf(".") === -1) {
        return true;
      }

      if(tempInput.indexOf(".") !== -1 && str !== ".") {
        var lastSubstr = tempInput.substring(tempInput.indexOf("."));
        if (lastSubstr.length < 3) 
        {
            return true;
        }
      }


      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }

  }
});
```

**see this link** : https://plnkr.co/edit/1fvI3grvZUzJCuqwJRXA?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
<span ng-if="userinput == selectedvalue">
match
</span>
```

and change

```
<input type="number" ng-model="userinput">
```

to

```
<input type="text" ng-model="userinput">
```

expected output

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">



 please select
  <select ng-model="selectedvalue">
          <option value="Number">Number</option>
          <option value="Decimalnumber">Decimalnumber</option>
        </select><br>
  <p>Selected: {{selectedvalue}}</p>

  <input type="text" ng-model="userinput">
  <span ng-if="userinput == selectedvalue">
    match
  </span>
</body>
```

Comment: how can i achieve decimal validation

Comment: $scope.selectedvalue = null;

$scope.userinput = null;

<input type="number" ng-model="userinput">

Comment: it means text box is disabled in the first place ? and wait for user to select a number and enabled the text box ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `ng-pattern` to dynamic change rules of an input field.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.inputTypes = [{
     name: "Number",
     regex: "\\d+"  
  },
  {
     name: "Decimal",
     regex: "^\\d*\\.\\d{1,2}$"
  }];
  $scope.selectedregex = $scope.inputTypes[0].regex;
  $scope.userinput = "";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  please select
  <select ng-model="selectedregex">
     <option ng-repeat="type in inputTypes" value="{{type.regex}}">
        {{type.name}}
     </option>
  </select><br>
  <p>Selected regex: {{selectedregex}} </p>

  <form name="form">
    <input name="input" ng-pattern="selectedregex" ng-model="userinput" /><br />
    <span ng-show="!form.input.$valid">Please enter valid input</span>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: if user select decimal input field allow only 2 decimal places

Comment: @koo005 I have updated regex to `^\\d*\.\\d{2}$`. Change regex to your requirements.

Comment: @koo005 So you don't want the error message instead you want to stop input taking values after 2 decimal places?

Comment: @koo005 It's good practise to show error message than restricting user as you can always disable form from submitting on error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158485/discussion-between-koo-005-and-mrnobody).