# validating one field with another field in angular reactive form

Tags: angular, forms, validation, reactive

i want solution for same example in reference link in angular latest version. validating textbox with dropdown validation values in Angular 10 or any angular version. Reference link solved in stack overflow [How to validate textbox based on dropdown value in angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47173722/how-to-validate-textbox-based-on-dropdown-value-in-angularjs)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional required validation in angular reactive form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52866016/conditional-required-validation-in-angular-reactive-form)

Answer (score 2):

I will write my solution on a similar topic, and you customize it for yourself:

I check if the password fields are the same:

1. Create validator

```
export class PasswordConfirmationValidator {
   
   static checkPasswordsAreTheSame(formGroup: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null {
       const password = formGroup.get('password')?.value;
       const confirmPassword = formGroup.get('confirmPassword')?.value;
       
       if (password !== confirmPassword) {
           return {
               notTheSame: true
           };
       }
       return null;
   }
}
```

2. Add this validator to form:

```
this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
            password: [null, [Validators.required]],
            confirmPassword: [null, [Validators.required]]
        }, {
            validators: PasswordConfirmationValidator.checkPasswordsAreTheSame
        });
```

Since the validator has access to the entire form, you can get any control and work with it